# identifying and printing out currency symbols in c

Tags: c, currency

I am currently working on an assignment, part of which I am having trouble with. I need to be able to identify 5 different currency symbols ($, £, ¥, €, ₹) from the terminal and print them back. This is the function I assigned to complete this portion. 
We were told by the professors to use the UTF-8 code combinations for each of them to recognize the individual symbols. All that this function is attempting to do is see if the next character is one of the symbols, and if so print that specific symbol. If it doesn't recognize any of the 4 "foreign" currencies, it will default the symbol to being a $, even if it was a digit or different symbol. Thanks for the help!

```
determcur()
{
    char c = getchar();
    if(c == 0xC2)
    {
            c = getchar();
            if(c == 0xA3)
            {
                    printf("%c%c", 0xC2, 0xA3);
            }
            if(c == 0xA5)
            {
                    printf("%c%c", 0xC2, 0xA5);
            }
    }
    if(c == 0xE2)
    {
            c = getchar();
            if(c == 0x82)
            {
                    c = getchar();
                    if(c == 0xAC)
                    {
                            printf("%c%c%c", 0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC);
                    }
                    if(c == 0xB9)
                    {
                            printf("%c%c%c", 0xE2, 0x82, 0xB9);
                    }
            }
    }
    else printf("%c", 0x24);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are having trouble with?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You won't get an answer if you don't ask a question.

Comment: Sorry first time I've used this site, the problem is that it doesn't recognize the symbols when they are typed in and instead always returns $.

Comment: @user3238882: Is a `char` signed or unsigned? If it is signed (likely), how can it store values larger than 127, and how can it be equal a value that's larger than 127 (like 0x82, or 0xAC, or...)?

Comment: you should add comment and use `'<char>'` if possible, don't use hexcode like that, no one will know which character are you talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lot of C compilers a `char` is a signed 8-bit integer.

A signed 8-bit integer can only hold values from -128 to 127. They can not hold a value like 0x80, 0xE2, etc.

For something like `if(c == 0xAC)` the compiler knows that the value in `c` can't be higher than 127, and therefore knows that the condition must be false. For this reason, a compiler can optimise your code (by eliminating all code that can't be reached due to "must be false" conditions) down to `getchar();printf("%c", 0x24);`.

To fix this use `uint8_t` instead of `char`. If you can't find a `uint8_t` (e.g. you're stuck with an ancient dialect of C) then use an `unsigned char`.

However..

It's possible that the input is actually coming from a file or something and not coming from the keyboard at all. For this reason you should handle `EOF` properly. `EOF` will not fit in a (signed or unsigned) `char` and will not fit in a `uint8_t` either. This means you should store the value returned by `getchar()` in an `int`, then compare with `EOF`, then cast it to `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` with a type cast to compare it 0xAC.

Basically, it becomes a bit like this:

```
    int c;

    c = getch();
    if(c == EOF) exit(0);
    if( (uint8_t)c == 0xC2) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Helped so much! Thank you so much for explaining everything step by step and giving different options for solving the problem.